# Possible to incorporate "push email" into a web app?

Tags: email, web-applications, gmail, imap, push-notification

I was reading about this new feature in Gmail called [push email](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-sync-now-with-push-gmail-support.html) which seems to be designed with smart phones in mind.

But I wonder if it would be possible to incorporate this into a web app.

So for example, let's say I allow Gmail to push email to a particular HTML form and then I have my web app process the emails.

Would that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

I'd expect the way to go would to have an IMAP client run on your web server and your web app handle the incoming mail.

Answer (score 0):

is there any ruby implementation for imap idle or the push imap ? i saw conflicting answers for net/imap too. it would be great if there is a rails gem which implements this feature